# Get value of DisplayField beforeRender

Tags: extjs, extjs6, displayfield

I have a displayfield as follows

```
 {
      fieldLabel: 'Designation', name: 'designation', xtype: 'displayfield',
      listeners: {
            beforerender: 
            {
                   fn: function (v) {
                        // get value here
                   },
                   scope: this
            }
      }
}
```

I tried to get value of displayfield using

```
v.getValue(), v.el.getValue(), v.getEl().getValue()
```

But everytime it shows undefined.

I also tried changing `beforerender` listener to `render`. But still the value id undefined.

Can anybody help me out of it.

Comment: How are u setting the Value for this DisplayField ?

Comment: @JChap: I have the JSON response and the value of 'designation' is binding to displayfield using  `name: 'designation'`

Comment: Need some more info, Are you using form.loadRecord/form.setValues to bind the json to form or are you using viewModel to bind the data ?

Answer (score 0):

So, as I understand it - you're relying on the form to populate the displayfield.

Given that's the case, the value is populated after rendering - so it won't be available during the rendering process.

You can prove that by creating a `setValue` method of your own, and putting a breakpoint in. This will let you see when the value is populated, relative to the rendering process.

Without more details on how you get the JSON object and when it's used to populate the form, I can't help you much more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The JSON value I am getting is fetched from database. and it is populated on the form on form load. I understand the value wont be available before render. I just want the actual JSON value which I am getting from database

Comment: It won't be available at the time of rendering either, though. The form will render and then populate the values afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are loading the value using a store proxy, you can listen to the store's *load* event rather than the view's render event since the store data is loaded into the view only after the view is rendered completely.